# Instance and Constant variables

Tags: java

I was wondering is a variable could be both instance and constant? For example would

`private final int Min=25;`

be both an instance variable and a constant variable?

Comment: constants are not felt to be variables. Their names say it all: variables can change value (if primitive) or reference (if a reference variable), while constants can't. They can be assigned only once.

Comment: `final` keyword prevents the value from being changed after it is initialised.
If you define the variable to be instance variable than each instance of the object will have it's own separate `final` value which is pointless unless you initialise the value in the constructor - AFAIR it is the only place where the compiler will let you initialise it.

Comment: To add on that, `final` is not for anything that varies.

Comment: However, yes, constants  an be final, if that is what you're wondering.

Comment: @GermannArlington beat me to it by a second

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The JLS does have a definition for `constant variables` and it is exactly what OP is asking about.

Comment: Yeah, @Hovercraft.  The JLS, man!

Comment: In terms of the JLS, it's important to note that `Min` is considered constant specifically because it's initialized with a *constant expression*, not just because it's final.

Comment: @GermannArlington - not quite.  You can also initialise it in the declaration (like in OP's example).  But you can't do it both in the constructor _and_ in the declaration.

Comment: @DavidWallace If your instance variable is initialised the same way as in the OP's post than it will be identical for all instances, in which case you may as well declare it `static`.

Answer (score 6):

[The Java Language Specification has a chapter on variables.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12)

> A variable is a storage location and has an associated type, sometimes
>   called its compile-time type, that is either a primitive type (§4.2)
>   or a reference type (§4.3).

There are different types of variables: class, instance, local, method parameter, exception parameter in `catch` block, constructor parameter, and array components.

There are also [`final` variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) which can only be assigned once.

If you declare a non-`static` field in a class, that is considered an [instance variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3).

[The JLS also says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

> **A variable of primitive type or type `String`, that is final and
>   initialized with a compile-time constant expression (§15.28), is
>   called a constant variable.**

So yes, yours is both an instance and constant variable.

Answer (score 5):

From [Chapter 4 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html)

In section 4.12.3

> An instance variable is a field declared within a class declaration without using the keyword static

In section 4.12.4

> A variable of primitive type or type String, that is final and initialized with a compile-time constant expression (§15.28), is called a constant variable.

So, yes, this is both a constant variable and an instance variable.

Feel free to use the term "constant variable".  It sounds oxymoronic, but the JLS uses it, so you are fine to do so.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, your example would be both an instance and a constant.

There are reasons for having an instance variable that can't be changed.

One is having clear and easy to read code. When you see a variable as final early on, you dont have to worry later on in the program if it is changing value or reference. This allows you to focus on other parts of the program where variables actually are changing.

Take a look at [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12) for more info on variables

Answer (score 0):

`Instance Variable` : an instance variable is a variable defined in a class (i.e. a member variable), for which each object of the class has a separate copy, or instance.

For example :

```
class MyClass { 
   int a; // instance variable;
   People p; // instance variable;
   static int b; // not instance variable. because all instances of class MyClass use same variable b
   static People community; // not instance variable with same reason.
}
```

`Constant` : a constant is an identifier whose associated value cannot typically be altered by the program during its execution. In Java, there isn't no real constant as C#. In C#, you declare constant is :

```
// C# Code
const int a = 3; // true
const int a; // wrong. because constant must permently have value. because it cannot have another values in their life.
```

But in Java, there is just : a variable that you can initialize **only one time**. and you use it final :

```
// Java Code
final int a = 3; // true
final int b; // still true. you can declare it later
```

So. combine above knowledge, you can say your example : `private final int Min=25;` is both instance variable and "const" variable (java doesn't have const variable, remember)

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

An [instance variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable) is a variable that every instance of a class is going to have its own version of. For example, if you have a Car class, an instance variable of Car might be `color`. Each time you make a new instance of Car, you can set its color instance variable.

A constant just means that it is unable to change after assignment -- it must also be *initialised with a constant expression* (thanks David!). So for the Car class, you could instantiate a new Car object with a specific color instance variable. In the Car class code, you could use the final keyword to make the color unchanging after it is set.

Yes, an instance variable can be defined as a constant.

Comment: My feedback: your answer is neither wrong nor right. These types of questions are usually best suited to an answer translated from the JLS. (There are two answers that do that pretty well if you want an example.) The reason that I say it's not right is because the JLS actually has a definition for constant and it's not just being final (but the OP may not know this either). Your answer is more right than wrong though. It's good for a first try.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Matthew.  I DO find your answer slightly wrong.  As Radiodef has hinted here, and has also stated in a comment under the question, the JLS defines a constant variable as a final one which was _initialised with a constant expression_.  That's a stronger condition than just being unable to change.  If you go back and edit that into your answer, I will upvote you.

Comment: Radiodef: I see what you mean. Should have done more research! Thank you for your input!

David: Yes, I see what you mean as well, that is definitely a key distinction. I've edited my answer. Thank you!